# How do i observe new navigator inside app navigator?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have new navigator inside app main navigator and i want to observe new navigator push and pop methods, but it seems observer callbacks calls just for main navigator instead of new navigator. how can i fix it?

initializing :

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> newNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> _routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
onInit: (store) => _routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)),//I think problem is from this line
```

unsubcribe :

```
onDispose: (store) => _routeObserver.unsubscribe(this)
```

new navigator:

```
Navigator(
    key: newNavigatorKey,
    observers: [_routeObserver],
    onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            routs[routeSettings.name],
      );
    })
```

container class:

```
class CategoryNavigator extends StatelessWidget with RouteAware
```

RouteAware mixin delegates:

```
  @override
  void didPop() {
    _routeState--;
    super.didPopNext();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    _routeState++;
    super.didPushNext();
  }
```

Comment: Why would you need 2 navigators? what is your use case?

Comment: I have a category explorer that has a history bar inside a single page, history bar must be same for all explorer screens. so i need new navigator to change pages inside a single page.

Comment: Why can't you use the same navigator and just skip the route to this single page?

Comment: because there is shared explorer widget that must be same for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're observing main navigator events instead of the one that you've created is, as you pointed out the line in which the error is.

```dart
onInit: (store) => _routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context))
```

The `context` your passing here is of the widget that is building `Navigator` in it's build().

That means it is above that Navigator you created in the widget tree. Therefore you're getting events for main Navigatot

Comment: thanks harsh, but whats the fix? how can i access right context?